# change pickerview's data by tablecell click

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uipickerview

i have a UITableView with 3 UITableViewCells and 3 Picker Views with other data.

Picker1 have Data1

Picker2 have Data2

Picker3 have Data3

this with the code:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row      forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
if (thePickerView.tag == 1) {
    return [data1 objectAtIndex:row];
} else if (thePickerView.tag == 2) {

return [data2 objectAtIndex:row];        

} else if (thePickerView.tag == 3) {

    return [data3 objectAtIndex:row];

}
return [data1 objectAtIndex:row];

}
```

i want to change picker view's data with a UITableViewCell. how i can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this create memberVariable **NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath** in .h file and make its property.

Now in tableViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndexPath = [indexPath retain];
    //reload pickerview here
}
```

Picker View Delegate method will be like this:

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
          titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
  switch (selectedIndexPath.row) 
  {
    case 0:
        //first cell selected picker view
        break;
    case 1:
        //second cell selected picker view
        break;
    case 2:
        //third cell selected picker view
        break;
     default:
     break;
  }
}
```